# Cypress : Not able to launch URL using cy.visit

Tags: cypress

I am trying to visit one URL which is my company's internal application using cypress automation. I am able to launch it manually. BUt with cy.visit() produces following error.

PLease note : though it's an internal application , I can still access it from outside.Please help

Cypress version:3.1.3
NPM : 6.5.0 
OS:Windows 7

[image]

Comment: What do you mean with "launch URL"? It seems like your web server is somehow inaccessible.

Comment: Launch URL means trying to load that URL. This URL is a public one. Anybody can access it from anywhere.

Comment: Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: Yes...Behind corporate proxy

Comment: It's probably related with [this issue](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/1469).

Comment: i set http_proxy and https_proxy environment variables and it worked